# A minus sign on the truncation error: Crank-Nicolson method for a diffusion equation with consume

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, truncation-error

I was studying by first time truncation error on finite schemes and the author of the article I am studying states the equation:

> $u_t=u_{xx}-1$

and the truncation error

> $T_m^{n+1}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x_m,t_{n+1/2})-\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x_m,t_{n+1/2})\fbox{$-1$}$.

I was wondering why the minus sign, i.e., I thought by intuition it would be:

$T_m^{n+1}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x_m,t_{n+1/2})-\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x_m,t_{n+1/2})\fbox{+1}$.

Thank you in advance to explain because this is non-intuitive.

Comment: Your reasoning could be right, if you could tell us what it has to do with truncation errors? I would at least expect higher order derivatives as the remainder terms of the discretizations.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, yes, it becomes on the text $T_m^{n+1}=[u_t-u_{xx}\fbox{$-1$}]^{n+1/2}_{m}-\dfrac{1}{12}[(\Delta x)^2u_{xxxx}+(\Delta t)^2u_{ttt}]^{n+1/2}_m$. Many thanks for attention.

Comment: Then yes, as the aim of this computation is that the first term cancels and the $O(Δx^2+Δt^2)$ term remains as dominating the truncation error.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, sorry, I could not understand very well your comment. The definition of the truncation term varies with the aim of computation? I could not understand yet why the minus sign. Many thanks and sorry, I am beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the author and he told me there's a typo here and the signal must be $+$. Many thanks for attention.